# ASP.NET attempting to load streamed video source into HTML5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, html5-video

Over the last few weeks I have been working on an ASP.NET WebAPI that was designed to stream video from one of the company servers and play it on an HTML5 `<video>` element. Following [a guide on C# Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asynchronous-videos-live-streaming-with-asp-net-web-apis-2-0/), we got the API published and now when the link for one of our videos is pasted into a browser, it starts to download (which, by the way, I'm not sure if it's supposed to do that when all we're trying to do is stream).

The files we need to stream are `mp4` and are going to be used largely on iOS devices through Safari. And before anyone asks: `srcVid` is programmed and confirmed to be able to encode .mp4 files successfully, as we have managed to hard-code videos into this element with no issue. With that said, this is how the page handles its HTML5 elements:

```
<video autoplay muted id="trainVid" style="width: 75%; height: auto;" controls>
   <source id="srcVid" runat="server"
     type='video/mp4; codecs*="avc1.424085, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

On the API side, here are how the videos are processed, largely following the example set by the C# article, as well as some help from a [Stephen Cleary article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/10/async-pushstreamcontent.html):

```
public class VidService
{
    public async void WriteVidBytes(Stream outputStream,
      HttpContent content, TransportContext tc)
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = "\\\\server\\link\\to\\file.mp4";
            int bufferSize = 1000;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(
              filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
                while (fileSize > 0)
                {
                    int cnt = fileSize > bufferSize ? bufferSize : fileSize,
                        readBufferSize = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, cnt);
                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBufferSize);

                    fileSize -= readBufferSize;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (HttpException ex) { return; }
        finally { outputStream.Close(); }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetVidContent()
    {
        // NOTE: please see the Edit on 6/10
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new PushStreamContent(
              (Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext>)WriteVidBytes
            )
        };
        return httpResponse;
    }
}

public class VidController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly VidService vs = new VidService();

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetVid(int id)
    {
        return vs.GetVidContent(id);
    }
}
```

**Note that the actual program dynamically fetches video links through a Video.cs object*

And **finally** on the C# side:

```
protected void LoadVideo(int vidId)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        string.Format("http://mobileAPI.website.com/Vid/GetVid/" + vidId.ToString()));
    req.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    string jsonString;
    using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
    }
    srcVid.Src = jsonString;
}
```

When opening the page, `LoadVideo()` seems to execute with no errors -- but after this, the page goes blank and hangs forever. I'm thinking this may be because I'm putting the wrong value into `srcVid.Src`, but if I don't put in the jsonString, then what **do** I put in for the source?

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated! If I missed anything obvious, please let me know, as this is the first time I have worked with WebAPI.

## UPDATE 1 (6/10)

I made a secondary method that took `WriteVidBytes` and turned it into a `Task` -- and other than turning it into a Task, the code inside is exactly the same. Another difference, also, is how `GetVidContent` fetches the data:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetVidContent(int vId)
{
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new PushStreamContent(async
          (outputStream, httpContext, transportContext) =>
        {
            await WriteVidTask(outputStream, httpContext, transportContext);
        }),
    };
    return httpResponse;
}
```

However, the page still hangs even though there is no problem getting the file through Postman or Fiddler.

Comment: Remove `async`  from `async void`, and replace the `await` with synchronous `output.Write`

Comment: @user1344783 I'll try it, but is that a good idea? I have never heard of anyone streaming a video synchronously.
EDIT: this yields the same result anyway

Comment: PushStreamContent also has a constructor that takes an real async lambda: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995250(v=vs.118), so you can convert your `async void` into `async Task` and remove the cast `(Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext>)`

Comment: @user1344783 I have just updated the question

Comment: I still think you should use async Task instead of async void 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [an example from Robert Huang on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820146/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-ASP-NET-Web-API-Video), I was able to get the video to stream through API without any issue.

The first thing I changed was the way that the `<video>` reads the source. Rather than a JSON string, the video loads the API link.

```
srcVid.Src = "http://api.website.com/Vid/GetVid?id=" + vidId.ToString();
```

Following the CodeProject link, I created an `HttpResponseMessage`, very similar to the one provided -- only this one supports asynchronous loading:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetVidContent(RangeHeaderValue rh, FileInfo fi)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
    long totalLength = fi.Length;


    if (rh == null || !rh.Ranges.Any())
    {   // treat request normally if there is no range header
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (outputStream, 
            httpContent, transpContext) =>
        {
            using (outputStream) // copy file to output stream straightforward
            using (Stream inputStream = fi.OpenRead())
            {
                try
                {
                    await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream, ReadStreamBufferSize);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }, GetMimeNameFromExt(fi.Extension));
        return response;
    }

    long start = 0, end = 0;

    if (rh.Unit != "bytes" || rh.Ranges.Count > 1 || TryReadRangeItem(rh.Ranges.First(),
        totalLength, out start, out end))
    {
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
        response.Content = new StreamContent(Stream.Null);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(totalLength);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = GetMimeNameFromExt(fi.Extension);

        return response;
    }

    var contentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(start, end, totalLength);

    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (outputStream, httpContent, transpContext) =>
    {
        using (outputStream)
        using (Stream inputStream = fi.OpenRead())
            await CreatePartialContent(inputStream, outputStream, start, end);
    }, GetMimeNameFromExt(fi.Extension));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = end - start + 1;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = contentRange;

    return response;
}
```

Any methods from the CodeProject article used in `await` areas were marked with the `async` expression.